# Django: QuerySet with objects where one time is earlier than another

Tags: django

I have a Django model `TimeThingie` with two `TimeField`s called `t1` and `t2`.

How do I get all `TimeThingie` objects where `t1 < t2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[F-objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model) might be what you want.

```
TimeThingie.objects.filter(t1__lt=F('t2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use F() fields to reference other fields on the model. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model for how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`QuerySet.extra()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra-select-none-where-none-params-none-tables-none-order-by-none-select-params-none) to add custom fields and conditions to the query.